# Need help to learn web services/web apps

Tags: web-services, web-applications, ejb-3.0, java-ee-5, seam3

I have been working as a Java developer for past 5 years with products completely developed in core Java and Java Swings. Now I have moved to a new company where I would be doing similar work at the back end , but the client I would have to learn web services, EJB , Seam and other web related stuffs. I would like to know where to get started, any useful books , tutorials both for in depth understanding and quick start as of now . Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IDE**

Get yourself the Netbeans IDE with the EE / Glassfish Bundle @
"http://netbeans.org/"

There is an EE and Web Tutorial section @ "http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html"

**Oracle Java EE Technologies (All Free)**

I find the JSR's are really good reference material and explanation of the technologies

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html

- JSR 250 - Common Annotations
        For EJB and web services you are going to need to get to grips with annotations
- JSR 315 - Servlet 3 Specification 
        This is a good read to get up to spec with servlets
- JSR 318 - Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1  (Covers stateless, timers, singletons)
        Also excellent read for EJB's
- JSR 224 - JAX-WS - This is the technology used for defining web services

**Packt Publishing (E-Books are really affordable)** 
Here are some good books (Just search for Java EE)

- Java EE 6 Development with NetBeans 7
- Java EE 6 Cookbook for Securing, Tuning, and Extending Enterprise Applications
- Seam 2 Web Development: LITE

**JBOSS.org**
"http://www.jboss.org"

- [Seam project documentation](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam2/Documentation)

**Red-Hat Access Portal**

If you have a subscription to any JBoss / Red-hat product, there are good document for EAS (Enterprise Application Server) including a Seam reference